# Bootstrap modal - Modal closing immediately on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to do a GET request to server and populate the modal with data from database. I am trying to make it like a API so that it is easier for me in the future.

By adding `showAjaxModal` class to all anchor tags, I am trying to automatically load the modal and do an ajax request to the `href` attribute of the anchor tag.

However, upon doing so, it all works but the modal immediately disappears and I get this error message:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43jj3q30/

Code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary showAjaxModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/api/path-to-request" data-target="#modal-id">Trigger modal</a>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-id">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div id="modal-loading-icon"></div>

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body ...
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

My Ajax code:

```
 $('.showAjaxModal').click(function (event) {
            var loadingIcon = $('.modal-loading-icon');
            var ajaxUrl = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxUrl,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    loadingIcon.show();
                }
            }).success(function (data) {

                event.preventDefault();
                loadingIcon.hide();
//              $('.modal-body').html(data);
                $('.modal-body').html('test');

            });
        });
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

change your link to:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary showAjaxModal">Trigger modal</a>
```

and add

```
$('#modal-id').modal('show'); //add this line to your success callback
```

-

```
success(function (data) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#modal-id').modal('show'); //add
   loadingIcon.hide();
   // $('.modal-body').html(data);
   $('.modal-body').html('test');

   });
```

**working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/43jj3q30/3/**

Comment: But I need to pass the `href` to the modal so I can do the ajax request. I cannot pass the href because it's removed

Comment: Use data-* attribute